# ImportError: 'WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied\n'

Tags: python-2.7, cython, importerror, win64

I am using python2.7 and pycharm as ide. I have two files named as experiment.py and low_dim_cython.pyx. When I try to run my code experiment.py, it throws access is denied error in importing functions from low_dim_cython. Code below belongs to experiment.py:

```
import numpy
import pyximport
pyximport.install(setup_args={'include_dirs':[numpy.get_include()]})
from low_dim_cython import read_basis, Dataset, AnonymizationScheme
```

Error is given:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PycharmProjects/deepLearning/PriView/experiment.py", line 23, in <module>
    from low_dim_cython import read_basis, Dataset, AnonymizationScheme, ensure_non_negative_consistency
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview2.7\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 458, in load_module
    language_level=self.language_level)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview2.7\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 233, in load_module
    exec("raise exc, None, tb", {'exc': exc, 'tb': tb})
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview2.7\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 215, in load_module
    inplace=build_inplace, language_level=language_level)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview2.7\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 191, in build_module
    reload_support=pyxargs.reload_support)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview2.7\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyxbuild.py", line 102, in pyx_to_dll
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview2.7\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview2.7\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview2.7\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 185, in run
    _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview2.7\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview2.7\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 193, in build_extensions
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview2.7\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 499, in build_extension
    depends=ext.depends)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview2.7\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 473, in compile
    self.initialize()
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview2.7\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 383, in initialize
    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview2.7\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 275, in query_vcvarsall
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview2.7\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview2.7\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
ImportError: Building module low_dim_cython failed: ['WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied\n']
```

I have given all privileges to pycharm and python.exe but it doesnt change anything.

Comment: Maybe this was a copy-paste error into SO (unsure how this would cause that exception...), but you have `pyximport.install` calling `pyximport.install`

Comment: I changed it, thank you.

Comment: FWIW, I think it's because you're doing `numpy`.  Like maybe the cython folks specifically prevent you from trying to do what you are?  Numpy is already setup, see the `cimport` discussion [here](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html#adding-types).  Good luck :S  Final sanity check: it's failing on the `pyx` file, try replacing the contents with one of their examples and see if it still breaks.  If so, maybe the file itself has bad permissions?

Comment: I will read the link that you gave me. But I dont think, the error is related with numpy. Because this code is used and work before with this order. I am just trying to run it to work on different data sets.

Comment: It looks like distutils cannot start `vcvarsall.bat`. I think nobody can tell you what is wrong with your system and you should start the debugger...